# wp_set_object_terms() without accents

Tags: sanitization, terms

How can I remove accents from term names before saving them to the database?

```
        // populate term
        if( empty ($d)) {
        } else {

            foreach ($d as $key=>$name){

                $d_term = $name;

                if ( has_term($d_term, $d_taxonomy)) {  
                // nothing happens
                } else {
                    wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $d_term, $d_taxonomy, true );
                }

            }   
        }
```

I tried using WP remove_accents function as well as similar php functions like:

`remove_accents($d_term);`

with no success.

Comment: Please reread your own question, it does not make sense

Comment: Can you elaborate precisely on what is happening? *"WP adds these names again and again..."* is a bit vague... What do you mean? Give us an example of a term with accents, the exact code you are using to sanitize the term, and the exact result e.g. how many times going into the database, etc... is it an infinite loop, is it adding the term 2 times, 10 times and how does a custom field relate to this if you are talking about terms?

Comment: I think this thread will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371697/replacing-accented-characters-php

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Upon saving a post the script checks if the taxonomy has terms. If it doesn't, then the script adds terms to the taxonomy. It works fine, however, if the terms already added to the taxonomy have accented characters, wordpress adds the same terms with accent to the taxonomy. This happens twice.

Comment: The name of a duplicated term are the same in database, their slugs are different. For example: Damián first saved: Damin, then: Damian.

Answer (score 1):

Just thought I'd point out, your call to `remove_accent()` is incorrect, you are missing the **s** off of accent**s**.

Example from codex:

```
$text = "Hoy será un gran día";
echo remove_accents($text);
```

> Echo result: Hoy sera un gran dia

- https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_accents

Comment: I corrected the code in my question - I used the correct call in functions.php, still the names got saved with accents.